# Laravel 5 - Individual class for specific user role

Tags: php, laravel, roles

I am using the following package for role handling in Laravel 5: [romanbican/roles](https://github.com/romanbican/roles)

Now I can access my testers and customers with the following syntax:

```
$testers = User::role('tester')->get();
$customers = User::role('customer')->get();
```

It would be really helpful if I could access my testers with the following syntax:

```
$testers = Tester::get();
```

Is there any possibility I could achieve this behaviour? I tried to subclass the User model but it didn't work as expected.

I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
class Tester {
    static function get() {
        return User::role('tester')->get();
    }
}
```